# Unable to find the pci device mentioned in the processor datasheet

Tags: firmware, intel

I have following intel processor `4th Generation Core Processor (Haswell U/Y)`.
I want to check the value of `PMBASE` register in the processor. For that I have downloaded the processor datasheet, where I found that `PMBASE` is present at B:D:F `0:1:0`. Here is the screenshot
[image]

The VID and DID of the device are mentioned below (from the same datasheet)
[image]

But, now when I am doing `lspci` from my linux machine, I am not seeing device `0:1:0`. I have even checked with chipsec tool. Even there I am not seeing any device with device id `0x0c01`. 
Any reason why such discrepancy is there?

Comment: What *do* you have near the root of the PCI device tree?

Comment: At `0:0:0` I have  Host bridge- DRAM controller. After that at `0:2:0`, I have VGA controller.

Comment: My guess is, it's not seeing in lspci output because it's pci express controller. Maybe there is some other way to list or access it.